# Typography/Typesetting: Footnotes of footnotes?

Tags: typography, typesetting, footnotes

Is it possible (by which I mean »allowed«) to create footnotes within footnotes? I am working on the design of a very intricate scientific publication and this question came up during a discussion of the typesetting of the footnotes. Are there any examples of a footnote containing a footnote in itself?

Comment: ‘Allowed’ by whom? There is no authority that will give you a fine and throw you in jail if you make footnotes in footnotes, no. Are there examples of it in existence? Yes. Is it normal? No. Will it annoy the designer immensely having to figure out a way to get an app like InDesign to create footnote footnotes? Yes. Is it a good idea to try? No.

Comment: Why would you need to? It's a footnote. Just add more to the first level footnote.

Comment: For whatever it’s worth, Terry Pratchett did this a few times.

Comment: @ZachSaucier: For the same reason you do regular footnotes: To avoid breaking the flow of the main text. If your footnote grows so large that it has a flow by itself (not that this is necessarily a good thing), it makes sense to avoid breaking it with a footnote.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft hats what i thought immediately too. But its not exactly good form Pratchett was doing humor after all.

Comment: Which journal is the text going to be published in? Have you been asked to follow a certain styleguide? (e.g. APA, Chicago, etc.)

Comment: JoSch, are you asking if its possible to do in something like TeX or InDesign, or are you asking if its allowed from a language perspective (in which case I'll migrate this to Writers.SE)